# How to build a ping message for ethereum node discovery using python?

Tags: ethereum, ping, packet, pyshark

I am trying to collect Ethereum node information from existing nodes. I would like to exchange `PING/PONG/FIND_NODE` messages from a seed node and identify more nodes recursively. As per the Ethereum documentation, I would require to build and exchange `PING/PONG` and `FIND_NODE/NODE` messages. However, I am not sure how the packet is built. Could anyone guidelines on how to build such packet messages?
Thank You